# On an HTTPS site I get a popup saying "This web site does not supply ownership information"

Tags: https

On an HTTPS website, I receiving a popup window saying "This web site does not supply ownership information." An image of popup is attached below.

Why is this popup appearing? How can I stop it?

[image: screenshot of popup window]

Comment: http://www.cknow.com/cms/articles/why-do-i-see-this-web-site-does-not-supply-ownership-information-in-my-browser.html

Comment: Is your problem the dialog spontaneously popping up, or the "This web site does not supply ownership information." part of it?

Answer (score 3):

Is this actually a popup alert you're seeing? It looks more like the "page information" window in Firefox, which you need to open yourself to see.

The vast majority of SSL/TLS certificates are what's called "domain validated" certificates. These are perfectly secure and unremarkable. They do *not* contain information about the owner of the website.

Financial institutions and a few other organizations often have "extended validation" certificates. These *do* contain ownership information, and will turn the address bar green in many browsers. In fact, the ownership information will also show up in the address bar:

[image: PayPal EV certificate]

And the owner will also show in the page information window:

[image: PayPal page information: Security]

Once again, the vast majority of websites do *not* have EV certificates, and this is perfectly normal.

If there's actually an *error* with the certificate, most browsers will actively block the connection. See [badssl.com](https://badssl.com/) for many examples of certs with errors, on which you can test your browser.

Answer (score -2):

usually that means that your browser doesn't contain the certificate for this secured site. You could install this certificate from the website itself into "trusted root certification authorities"

Answer (score -2):

If the website's SSL certificate is not signed by a valid certificate authority (CA), you will get that warning unless you install the servers public key on the client computer in question, which is hardly ever feasible for a public website.

Comment: Untrusted CA causes a very different warning or error, not the one in this Q